# Should I upload PHPMyAdmin to the server

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

This is going to be a very stupid question. But i'm new to php and programming all together. I would be launch my first every database powered website. I'm still a student in college, so please take it easy on me.

I was using PHPMyAdmin for my local development. I'm ready now to launch the website and wanted to ask. Should I upload PHPMyAdmin together with my website? Or Not?

Thanks a million. This is an easy question for most of you but I really dont know

Comment: Good question for [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), not so much here.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a tool to access/manipulate your database.  Whether or not you upload it to the server depends on whether you need it there or not.  Do you need to use it to access the DB?  If so, then upload it.  Just make sure it's secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I say no, it can become a security vulnerability if not properly secured - but that's completely up to you. If you get yourself a good GUI mysql client you'll save yourself a lot of time anyway.

Comment: This have the issue of opening MySQL remote connections (not binding only to localhost), which is not recommended. Nonetheless, if you have a good firewall setup, there should be no problem.

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't be a problem if they can restrict remote access to a single IP address, and only enable remote connections when administration is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not. If you are using a shared webhosting, they normally have an internal URL where you can manage your databases using phpMyAdmin. Or if you are using your own private server, install phpMyAdmin in another location under another hostname/port, and only allow connections from your IP.